# Benefit of using multiple checksums for a group in AIDE

Tags: security, hashsum, aide

What are the benefits to having all md checksum functions specified for a group when running AIDE?  For example, what is the difference between defining the first line and the second line with less md functions selected?

```
All=p+i+n+u+g+s+m+c+a+md5+sha1+tiger+rmd160

All=p+i+n+u+g+s+m+c+a+md5+sha1
```